# Concatenar colunas em uma única linha Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, query

Tenho uma situação, que facilitaria muito.. se conseguisse retornar os dados de uma coluna específica em uma única linha:

Por exemplo:

Tabela A:

```
Codigo | Descricao
-------------------
1      | Descricao 1
2      | Descricao 2
3      | Descricao 3
```

Gostaria de montar um sql que me retornasse em uma única linha deste jeito:

```
1,2,3
```

Apenas a coluna código..

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como é possível fazer isto.. e se é possível?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilize a função `array_agg(expression)`:

```
Select array_agg(codigo) from tabela A
```

No link você pode ver a [documentação PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) para mais informações.

Comment: Só para ficar documentado, caso alguém no future busque a mesma coisa, utilizei uma função parecida..`Select string_agg(cast(codigo as text),',') from tabelaA` para voltar como um texto, e não um array (Como array retorna { } juntos). Mas sua resposta foi de fundamental importância. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE public.foobar
(
    Codigo BIGINT,
    Descricao TEXT
);
```

Dados:

```
INSERT INTO public.foobar( Codigo, Descricao ) VALUES ( 1, 'Descricao 1' );
INSERT INTO public.foobar( Codigo, Descricao ) VALUES ( 2, 'Descricao 2' );
INSERT INTO public.foobar( Codigo, Descricao ) VALUES ( 3, 'Descricao 3' );
```

Consulta:

```
SELECT string_agg( Codigo::text, ',' ) FROM public.foobar;
```

Saída:

```
1,2,3
```